# how to reach the settings in the advanced tab in the system properites via C# code ..?

Tags: c#, windows, controlpanel

I wonder if there's any way i could reach and change the check boxes in the performance options (visual effects) from C#.

Now I reached only the advanced tab by:

```
control.exe sysdm.cpl,0,3
```

but I didn't know a way to continue any further ..

Also, in general, is there a way that we could change somethings in the control panel 
via code ?
like increasing the mouse pointer speed, or adjusting screen resolution .. etc
(navigating via code)
it would be really cool .. :)

Comment: Um, that's going to change the value system wide, not just for your application. The user may have set the visual settings that way for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly set the values: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A similar theme has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897310/can-you-change-the-visual-effects-performance-settings-from-an-application).
You can also click controls on the windows with [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).